# silverlight wrappanel

Tags: silverlight

_http://www.mscui.net/PatientJourneyDemonstrator/PrimaryCare.htm

I want to create/design the similar to above site/url using silverlight. 
For this I have created separate user controls(Xaml files). Please advice me the steps/way to proceed in silveright. I am using silverlight versin 2.

I am thinking to use Wrappanel to adjust all the xmal files in Home page/default page. so that I can navigate to any page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the XAP from your internet cache, open it with any zip tool and then use something like reflector to look in the DLLs to get the XAML out, should you desire to see how they did it themselves.

There's actually a project on codeplex which demonstrates how to do this dashpart effect with full source code called [blacklight](http://www.codeplex.com/blacklight), so the above is probably not necessary.